# Anime with a boy wearing a sun-shaped crown

Tags: madou-king-granzort, mashin-hero-wataru

I found the following [picture](http://9gag.com/gag/am0oOe2) which collect a bunch of characters from many anime: I was curious about the two characters that I put in the red square (just below Ichigo). Which anime are they from?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The character on the left is [Wataru Ikusabe](http://myanimelist.net/character/8280/Wataru_Ikusabe) from [*Mashin Eiyuuden Wataru*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/3837/Mashin_Eiyuuden_Wataru).

[image]

The character on the right is [Daiichi Haruka](http://myanimelist.net/character/28122/Daiichi_Haruka) from [*Madou King Granzort*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2818/Madou_King_Granzort).

[image]

They are grouped together because both series are directed by Shuji Iuchi. In fact, there is a crossover of *Mashin Eiyuuden Wataru* in the first episode of *Madou King Granzort*:

[image]